# Is an Enum changing the behaviour of an Entity bad?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I am very new to Domain-Driven Design. I have come across a part of a domain which I'm not sure if I have modeled in the best way possible.

There is a `Membership` entity which has a membership type.

```
public enum MembershipType
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    TypeC,
    TypeD,
}
```

Each `Membership` can have 1 or some `Businesses` (max 2). `TypeA`, `TypeB` and `TypeC` will only ever have 1 `Business`, but `TypeD` must have 2 businesses. because of this requirement, I have ended up having an`IList<Business>` within the `Membership` entity as follows and I have a method called `AddBusinesses` which takes an array of Businesses. Simply put, the `MembershipType` `enum` changes the behaviour of the `Membership` entity and I'm not sure if I have modeled this in the best way possible or if there's a better way to tackle this.

```
public class Membership
{
    public MembershipType MembershipType {get; protected set;}
    private IList<Business> _businesses;
    public IReadOnlyList<Business> Businesses => _businesses;

    public Membership(MembershipType membershipType)
    {
        MembershipType = membershipType;
    }

    public void AddBusinesses(param Business[] businesses)
    {
        if(MembershipType == MembershipType.TypeD && businesses.Length != 2)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Membership Type D require 2 businesses");
        else if(businesses.Length != 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"MembershipType {MembershipType} require 1 business");

        foreach(var business in businesses)
        {
            _businesses.Add(business);
        }
    }
}
```

The `MembershipType` will hardly ever change, and if it changes, it will only be a new `MembershipType` rather than a change to an existing one.

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Thank you, everyone, for taking time to answer my question. I learned a lot from your answers. I think omitting part of the domain in this question was a mistake I made (sorry).

What if a `Business` entity doesn't have any meaning without a `Membership`. i.e. I can't construct a `Business` without having constructed a `Membership` first. There's an invariant in Business that depends on the `Membership.MembershipType` called `BusinessType`.

Comment: The `MembershipType` is not changing the behaviour so much as changing the definition of a legally constructed entity. It might be better, though, to have a constructor or factory method `createMembership(MembershipType, Business[])` so that the validation occurs in one step, and you never have an invalid Membership entity.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @BobDalgleish, I will try it out. In my current method, I always had to initiate the Membership first in an Invalid state and then call the AddBusinesses method. Factories will solve that issue as well. Cheers

Comment: As far as I can tell, membership type means nothing in your model. It is probably just a label used for commercial purposes. And going by your definition, it can be determined from the number of businesses present. So you may be better off by treating membership type as a read-only property that is not set but determined on demand by the number or businesses and maybe some other properties.

Comment: @MartinMaat But there are multiple MembershipTypes that has only 1 business.

Comment: @Amalia So what does make a membership type? Who or what determines it?

Comment: The user decides what membership (of type either TypeA, TypeB etc.) to create and that in turn determines how many Businesses it needs.

Comment: @MartinMaat: You're making a few too many assumptions there. It's perfectly possible that _different_ users decide the membership type and the related businesses. E.g. the manager forces something to be of type D; but the employees are responsible for adding the actual businesses at a later stage. You suggestion is good for some situations; but we don't conclusively know if this is one of them.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about that `protected set`. Is this class being subclassed? Is there a reason why a subclass might want to change the MembershipType? Also, is it ok that the `AddBusinesses` method allows for multiple calls without ever checking the length of the actual list `_businesses`?

Comment: @BgrWorker we are using Entity Framework Core 2.1 and the OwnsOne fluent configuration. At the moment, you can't give a backing field as an Owned property. Also, it needs a setter. So rather than having a public setter, I'm having a protected setter.

Answer (score 3):

Some purists may argue that this is inherently a bad design. My opinion is less strict on this.

Like many things in programming, there is a threshold of what's acceptable and what is not. Let's explore the extremes:

**Unacceptable**:

An entity which behaves completely differently in all of its properties/methods, based on the enum.

In such a case, you've basically merged several **separate** entities into a single one, and you use the enum to basically select which of the entity behavior you want to use.

**Acceptable**:

An entity which behaves the same regardless of the enum, except for a *small* percentage of its properties/methods.

In this case, the entities are still representing the same role, and the enum only has a minor impact on the entity as a whole.

A good example here would be a person's appelation based on their gender:

```
public string FormalName
{
    get
    {
        switch(this.Gender)
        {
            case Gender.Male:
                return $"Mr {this.LastName}";
            case Gender.Female:
                if(this.IsMarried)
                    return $"Mrs {this.LastName}";
                else
                    return $"Ms {this.LastName}";
        }
    }
}
```

This fits the bill for your question, it's an enum that changes the behavior of its entity. However, the change itself is only a small part of the entity's purpose, which makes it negligible in terms of needing refactoring.

For more abstract examples, some purists might advocate inheritance/interface implementation/composition. I have some colleagues who would definitely argue this standpoint.
But I find it overengineered and therefore first assess whether an abstraction is really warranted or not. In this case, I don't think it's warranted.

**So where do you fall on the spectrum?**

It's a bit hard to assess, since you've omitted part of your class that are not affected by the enum.

As far as I can see, the enum only decides the *validation* of the entity. This is acceptable, as long as you're not essentially using completely different fields/values between two different enums.

- If enum A requires FieldA and FieldB; and enum B requires FieldC and FieldD; then they are really two completely separate entities.
- If both enums require 10 fields, and only differ on one particular field that is required, then this is (IMO) acceptable behavior.

Ask yourself whether any of the alternatives would be better here:

- Is the distinction between the enums big enough to warrant separate entities?
- Is one of the enums a "more specific" version of another (more generalized) enum? If so, maybe you'd be better off having two entities that derive from each other.
- ...

---

**Code Review**

However, I do wonder about the method's purpose itself:

```
public void AddBusinesses(param Business[] businesses)
{
    if(MembershipType == MembershipType.TypeD && businesses.Length != 2)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Membership Type D require 2 businesses");
    else if(businesses.Length != 1)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"MembershipType {MembershipType} require 1 business");

    //...
}
```

The method seems to assume that when `AddBusinesses()` is called; that it is supplied with the **full list** of businesses.
I infer this based on the fact that you immediately throw an exception if not enough businesses have been supplied. If `_businesses` already contains one item, and I use the method to add a second item, there shouldn't be a validation error for `TypeD`, yet you will throw one anyway.

However, I would generally expect that `Add()` methods can be chained as well. Suppose I do this:

```
var myMembership = new Membership() { MembershipType = MembershipType.TypeD };

foreach(var business in myListOfFiveBusinesses)
{
    if(business.NeedsToBeAdded)
        myMembership.AddBusinesses(business);
}
```

This code would fail, because you would throw an exception when I add the first business. You never wait to see if I would have added more businesses!

The weird part is that the rest of the code does seem to work under the idea that this method could be called multiple times:

```
    foreach(var business in businesses)
    {
        _businesses.Add(business);
    }
```

Notice that this code adds the businesses to an **existing** list of `_businesses`.

If it were the case that a pre-existing list would be overwritten, I would expect different code here, e.g.

```
_businesses = businesses; //out with the old list!
```

It seems like your current `AddBusinesses()` method is being used inconsistently. The validation assumes that the given parameters **overwrite** any pre-existing list; but the subsequent logic assumes that the given parameters are **appended** to a pre-existing list.

Answer (score 3):

In my idea, all 5 of SOLID could be applied. Before starting with DDD (this is a high level of views.). I think we can start with some basic design with SOLID and gain more experience in designing the scope of models.
And their is no best way. Just find the most suitable implementation.
And here is my interests.

```
public interface IBusiness
{
}

public enum MembershipType
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    TypeC,
    TypeD,
}

public interface IMemberShip
{
   MembershipType Type { get; }
}

public abstract class MemberShip : IMemberShip
{
    public abstract MembershipType Type { get; }
}

public abstract class SingleBusinessMemberShip : MemberShip
{
    protected SingleBusinessMemberShip(IBusiness business)
    {
        Business = business ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(business));
    }

    public IBusiness Business { get; }
}

public abstract class MultipleBusinessesMemberShip : MemberShip
{
    protected MultipleBusinessesMemberShip(IList<IBusiness> businesses)
    {
        Businesses = businesses ??  throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(businesses));
    }

    public IList<IBusiness> Businesses { get; }
}
```

and membership subclasses should required business as need, depends on it is single business or multiple-business

```
public class TypeAMemberShip1 : SingleBusinessMemberShip
{
    public TypeAMemberShip1(IBusiness business) : base(business)
    {
    }

    public override MembershipType Type => MembershipType.TypeA;
}

public class TypeAMemberShip2 : SingleBusinessMemberShip
{
    public TypeAMemberShip2(IBusiness business) : base(business)
    {
    }

    public override MembershipType Type => MembershipType.TypeA;
}

public class TypeDMemberShip1 : MultipleBusinessesMemberShip
{
    public TypeDMemberShip1(IList<IBusiness> businesses) : base(businesses)
    {
    }

    public override MembershipType Type => MembershipType.TypeD;
}

public class TypeDMemberShip2 : MultipleBusinessesMemberShip
{
    public TypeDMemberShip2(IList<IBusiness> businesses) : base(businesses)
    {
    }

    public override MembershipType Type => MembershipType.TypeD;
}
```

Comment: Note that "applying SOLID" is usually a matter of _degree_, not a binary on/off switch. Other than that sidenote; I like your approach _if_ OP's case warrants such an abstraction. Based on the OP's code, I can't conclusively say if this level of abstraction is warranted.

Comment: @Flater, Yes, I agree with you, but just want to introduce my idea that follows some points in SOLID I learned (from zero to applying..)
About OP's code, The abstraction is for making sure that when we have a new business behavior (e.g.NonBusinessMemberShip), we do not need to modify the abstracts which will affect the existing code base.

Comment: That is highly dependent on the change. E.g. a possible future expansion of a `Gender` enum (to include non-binary choices) does not warrant making separate classes for every gender on the list. The open/closed principle does not apply in cases wherebusiness requirements **change** (not just get extended). Note that the `Gender` enum can still impact the behavior of the class, e.g. in a decision between using Mr/Ms/Mrs. Your answer is correct for _sufficiently large_ impact of behavior between different enum values; but this is not yet proven to be sufficiently large to warrant doing so.

Answer (score 1):

**A healthy application of the Open/Close principle is what's needed here**

> the MembershipType enum changes the behaviour of the Membership entity

Not if `MembershipType` is encapsulated in the appropriate abstraction. Make a `Businesses` class, which naturally will know it's own required minimum & maximum number of businesses. Then the `Membership` knows only - is told by the businesses object -  if the `Businesses` is full or not, regardless of what `MembershipType` it is.

---

**Is `MembershipType` model missing something?**

It's hard to imagine your customers have these terms meaning only the number of allowable businesses. There must be more to it. If so a `Businesses` class is a good start for making the concept extensible in code.

As a consequence `Membership` becomes a thoroughly consistent API for everything `MembershipType`ish. Exposing mundane details, as seen in `AddBusinesses` method, ruins extensibility and kills a good API.

---

**Construction**

Use a factory as suggested by @BobDalgleish which will inject the custom `Businesses` via a `Membership` constructor. And use `MembershipType` to tell the factory what to build.

Whether the `MembershipType` value itself becomes part of that class is a design issue. But don't be a leaky abstraction by making it public to let, or force(!), `Membership` or any `Businesses` client, do what `Businesses` should to for itself. Mind your own business.